# Python - save binned data to text file

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I want to save some histogram data in a csv file. This is the code I came up with:

```
ExportName_csv = 'ExportData/' + FileName + '.csv'
freq, bins = np.histogram(ValList,bins)
np.savetxt(ExportName_csv, izip(freq, bins), delimiter="\t")
```

For each bin I want to save the bin value and the corresponding count `freq` in `ExportName_csv`. I want values regarding different to be bins in different lines; in each line values are separated by a comma.

With the current code I get the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. What do you suggest to do?

Full traceback is:

```
np.savetxt(ExportName_csv, izip(freq, bins), delimiter="\t") 
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/nump‌​y/lib/npyio.py", line 976, in savetxt ncol = X.shape[1] 
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Sample `ValList` and complete traceback will help to answer your question faster.

Comment: And beware that comma is `','`, and `'\t'` is tabulation

Comment: Here's the complete traceback:     `np.savetxt(ExportName_csv, izip(freq, bins), delimiter="\t")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 976, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: And here you can find an example of the `ValList` values, printed using `json.dump(ValList, f)`: http://cl.ly/text/2n420p2o2Y3S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, comma is `','`, not `\t`.

Second, you should use `zip`, not `izip`:

```
>>> data = zip(*np.histogram(ValList,bins))
>>> np.savetxt('test.txt', data, delimeter=',')
```

Comment: Beware, the length of `bins` is always one longer than of `freq`, so `zip` cuts off the last bin edge.  If the bins are equally spaced, no information is lost, but you should be aware of it.

Comment: @askewchan if some other user opens the csv file, they won't know that the last bin is cut off. So unless you also supply some header, the creater should be carefull.